# How can I get rid of the black background in Aptana and make it the normal white?

Tags: javascript, html, aptana

I just started using Aptana 3.0 and the background in the area where you write code is black with the font white. I'd like to change this to black on white like most normal IDEs. I tried changing the colors in preferences>general>editors>text editors but nothing happens when I do.
Any help on how to change this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Themes

Comment: From that article, the menu you're after is `Preferences > Aptana > Themes`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of aptana studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339037/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-aptana-studio)

Answer (score 33):

This is called Themes. Aptana Studio 3.0 uses black one by default. It could be changed in Preferences. (menu Window/Preferences, Aptana/Themes).

Answer (score 4):

window -> preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Themes -> (select a theme from dropdown )
"Dreamweaver" theme has white background.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes->Aptana Studio 2.x

This is the good ol' white background from Aptana 2.

Answer (score -1):

Go to:

> Aptana Studio 3 > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes

There you can change the Theme from the dropdown menu, to one that has a white background (such as Sababa).