# How do I change the background color of aptana studio?

Tags: background, aptana

How do I change the black background of the Aptana IDE (or the entire theme) to a different one, like blue?

Comment: I actually think that this is a reasonable question. There is a list of built-in themes in Window->Preferences->Aptana->Themes.

Comment: I have to agree with @EricGustavson I had quite a deal of difficulty working this out as well.

Comment: I also agree with @EricGustavson.  Without Eric's answer I would have searched much longer.  Stackoverflow is my first address for questions like this.

Comment: I love that this question is the third result in the linked google search:)

Comment: A simple google search led me to this result.

Comment: A simple spin through the preferences lead me to the answer--is using an IDE really so complicated, particularly in comparison to the actual work of development?

Comment: Since this question is closed (which is a really stupid thing btw) I try to answer it in the comments: go to Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes and select Eclipse theme

Answer (score 18):

As gyozo mentioned in the comment, for a blue theme, use

> Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes

and select the Eclipse theme.

Comment: Hello Lanceroberts can you please answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967547/can-i-change-the-background-color-of-inactive-tabs-in-aptana-3) question?

Answer (score 5):

Its simple just go to ->

Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Default background color in Text Editors window seems to be black. No matter whar I do I am not able to change it.

Here's what I do:

**Right click ind the editors window
Select "Preferences" at the fly-out menu
Select "General > Editors > Text Editors"
Change "Background color" in the appearance box from black to anything
Click "Apply".**

The change is made to the background of the line numbers in that column.

Answer (score 3):

It's just very simple!

Just do: **Window** next go to **Preferences** then **Aptana Studio** finally click **Themes**
and select your theme!

Answer (score 0):

To change the master theme do as above, but if you want to change the editor theme, go to

Window -> preferences -> aptana studio -> publishing -> themes

In Aptana 3.6.1 "editor theme" is the second option in that tree.
You can use one of the built-in themes or import your own.