# Can I change the background color of inactive tabs in Aptana 3

Tags: ide, themes, aptana, aptana3

I've changed Aptana to the "Dark" theme, but no I can barely read the inactive tabs. Is there a way of just changing the background or font colour of the inactive tabs ?

Comment: Yeah I've searched all options and sub-options in Window-> Preferences. But cannot find any option related to inactive tabs' color and font. Please anyone answer for this question.